# Node.js: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined in route

Tags: node.js, express

I am  trying to implement my first user login authentication with jwt. I have a registration endpoint, where I have populated fake data. Now I want to login with the data I have in database. I am testing via Postman, but I have an error which is

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  email: 'fakeEmail@gmail.com\t',
  password: '12345678'
}
(node:14781) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined
    at /home/me/coding/project/backend/routes/user.js:38:40
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:14781) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14781) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
POST /user/login - - ms - -
```

Assuming it might be because of bodyparser, i have tried both way 
`//app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser());`
but same error.
Here is my login endpoint

````
router.post("/login",(req, res) => {
  const {email, password } = req.body; 
  console.log(req.body)
  pool
    .query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $1 AND password = $2 LIMIT 1", [email, password ])
    .then(res => {
       const data =  res.rows[0];
      if ( email  && password === data.password) {
      const token = jwt.sign({ email: req.body.email }, "mySecretKey", {
        expiresIn: "30 day",
      });
      res.send(token);
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(401);
    }
    });
});```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was, that I have registration endpoint, where I am using Bcrypt, and I had to Verify in Login endpoint. Therefore I was getting errors.
 So, here is my corrected Login endpoint

```
router.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  pool
    .query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $1 LIMIT 1", [email])
    .then((result) => {
      const data = result.rows[0];
      if (result.rows.length > 0 && email) {
        bcrypt.compare(password, data.password, function (err, result) {
          if (result) {
            const token = jwt.sign({ email: req.body.email }, "mySecretKey", {
              expiresIn: "30 days",
            });
            res.send(token);
          } else {
            res.sendStatus(401);
          }
        });
      } else {
        res.sendStatus(401);
      }
    });
});
```

I hope, it will help someone having similar issue

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in `res` object try loging res in then block. res.rows[0] seems undefined

Comment: do you think problem is in SQL?

Comment: Is res is undefined ?

Comment: not res, but res.rows[0], I checked in console 'data' ```const data =  res.rows[0];```  as well, it's undefined

Comment: ok then console log res and check. Might you getting the result in some other variable inside res. I mean like this res.rows